# How to use results from mysql built-in functions when inserting via mysql-x-devapi in C++?

Tags: c++, mysql-x-devapi

I am using mysql-x-devapi and need to insert a row to a table and put `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` of the server in a column:

```
sql_client_.getSession().getDefaultSchema()
    .getTable("event")
    .insert("title", "time")
    .values("event title", "UNIX_TIMESTAMP()")
    .execute();
```

This code gives me:
CDK Error: Incorrect integer value 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP()' for column 'time' at row 1

How can I do this using xdevapi (not sql command that needs sql string)?

I am able to use `mysqlx::expr("UNIX_TIMESTAMP()")` in `set` function when updating the table. The same doesn't work with `insert` and fails with the following error:

```
/usr/include/mysql-cppconn-8/mysqlx/devapi/table_crud.h:157:17: error: ‘mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Expression::Expression(V&&) [with V = mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Expression&]’ is private within this context
  157 |       add_values(get_impl(), rest...);
```

Comment: This seems like a bug in xdevapi code, I was able to fix compile error by changing the source code and adding perfect forwarding on `values` function and `add_values` function called inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `mysqlx::expr("UNIX_TIMESTAMP()")`:

```
sql_client_.getSession().getDefaultSchema()
    .getTable("event")
    .insert("title", "time")
    .values("event title", mysqlx::expr("UNIX_TIMESTAMP()"))
    .execute();
```

then fixed the compile error by touching:

`/usr/include/mysql-cppconn-8/mysqlx/devapi/table_crud.h` replaced:

```
  template<typename... Types>
  TableInsert& values(Types... rest)
  {
    try {
      add_values(get_impl(), rest...);
      return *this;
    }
    CATCH_AND_WRAP
  }
```

with:

```
  template<typename... Types>
  TableInsert& values(Types&&... rest)
  {
    try {
      add_values(get_impl(), std::forward<Types>(rest)...);
      return *this;
    }
    CATCH_AND_WRAP
  }
```

`/usr/include/mysql-cppconn-8/mysqlx/devapi/detail/crud.h` replaced:

```
  template <typename... T>
  static void add_values(Impl *impl, T... args)
  {
    Add_value::Impl row{ {}, 0 };
    Args_processor<Add_value>::process_args(&row, args...);
    Add_row::process_one(impl, row.first);
  }
```

with:

```
  template <typename... T>
  static void add_values(Impl *impl, T&&... args)
  {
    Add_value::Impl row{ {}, 0 };
    Args_processor<Add_value>::process_args(&row, std::forward<T>(args)...);
    Add_row::process_one(impl, row.first);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The X DevAPI user guide gives some hints about what should be supported or not. In that case, as you can see from the [function definition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/crud-ebnf-table-crud-functions.html#crud-ebnf-tableinsertfunction) documentation, the `values()` method expects a [`Literal`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/mysql-x-expressions-ebnf-definitions.html#expression-ebnf-literal), so, not even `mysqlx.expr()` will work.

In your case, looking at the error message, it means that the `time` column probably is some kind of `INTEGER` data type. Given `"UNIX_TIMESTAMP()"` is a string (because the expression is not being evaluated), it is not being coerced in any way and would only work for other column data types such as `VARCHAR`.

In theory, from what I can tell, there is nothing that really prevents the API from allowing computed expressions. The X Protocol accommodates [that](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/plugin/x/protocol/protobuf/mysqlx_crud.proto#L243) but I'm not entirely sure it is the same case for the X Plugin itself. I would suggest you request the feature using the public MySQL [bug tracker](http://bugs.mysql.com/) and the corresponding category (maybe `MySQL Connectors: Document Store: DevAPI`).

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js

Comment: It seems that documentation is not up to date. `mysqlx::expr()` worked in C++.

Comment: But that's because you changed the Connector/C++ implementation, right? As I mentioned, from the protocol (and apparently from the X Plugin) standpoint, there's nothing that prevents the API to allow that. But as far as I know, it does not (as per the documentation).

Comment: I just fixed a bug (as explained in my answer), the feature was already implemented.